# Managing two states in one action in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have two APIs reporting two sets of data (lockboxes and workstations). The lockboxes API has a collection of agencies with a recordId that I need to manipulate. The workstations API is the main collection that will assign one of these agencies (lockboxes) on a toggle to a workstation by sending the lockboxes.recordId and the workstation.recordId in the body to the backend.

My store looks like this

```
import { axiosInstance } from "boot/axios";

export default {
  state: {
    lockboxes: [],
    workstation: []
  },

  getters: {
    allLockboxes: state => {
      return state.lockboxes;
    },
    singleWorkstation: state => {
      let result = {
        ...state.workstation,
        ...state.lockboxes
      };
      return result;
    }
  },

  actions: {
    async fetchLockboxes({ commit }) {
      const response = await axiosInstance.get("agency/subagency");
      commit("setLockboxes", response.data.data);
    },
    updateAgency: ({ commit, state }, { workstation, lockboxes }) => {
      const postdata = {
        recordId: state.workstation.recordId,
        agency: state.lockboxes.recordId
      };

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axiosInstance
          .post("Workstation/update", postdata)
          .then(({ data, status }) => {
            if (status === 200) {
              resolve(true);
              commit("setWorkstation", data.data);
              commit("assignAgency", workstation);

              console.log(state);
            }
          })
          .catch(({ error }) => {
            reject(error);
          });
      });
    }
  },

  mutations: {
    setWorkstation: (state, workstation) => (state.workstation = workstation),
    assignAgency(workstation) { workstation.assign = !workstation.assign},
    setLockboxes: (state, lockboxes) => (state.lockboxes = lockboxes)
  }
};
```

Process:

When I select a lockbox from the dropdown and select a toggle switch in the workstation that I want to assign the lockbox too, I do get the lockbox to show but it goes away on refresh because the change only happened on the front end. I'm not really passing the workstation.recordId or lockboxes.recordId in my body as I hoped I was. It is not reading the state and recognizing the recordId for either state(workstation or lockboxes).

the console.log is returning (Uncaught (in promise) undefined)

The request is 404ing with an empty Payload in the body ( {} )

Not even the mutation is firing

template

```
toggleAssign(workstation) { 
  this.updateAgency(workstation); 
}
```

At some point I had it that is was reading the workstation.recordId before I tried to merge the two states in the getter but I was never able to access the lockboxes.recordId. How can I have access to two states that live in two independent APIs so I can pass those values in the body of the request?

Comment: Can you share what your `getters` return. 
Also can you share what do you get workstation and lockboxes as in `updateAgency`?

Comment: The answer has some good points, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60991870/3731501 . The problem cannot be solved until you'll sort out all inconsistencies. A good question requires https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to reproduce the problem, in case there are API calls, they can be mocked with static JSON file. Problems with API cannot be physically solved by other users because they don't have access to it. The efficient way to debug them is to ignore Vue and do this with with Postman. It's unknown what the response looks like.

Comment: *console.log is returning* - this is wrong, it doesn't return anything because you don't get nearly to this line. `.catch(({ error }) => { reject(error); })` doesn't serve a good purpose except that you don't know what the error is because you ignore it. The rejection doesn't have `error` property, this is the reason why you get *Uncaught (in promise) undefined*. `new Promise` is an antipattern because there's axios promise already, but try to replace `catch` with with `.catch(e => { console.error(e); reject(e))` to get the whole error.

Comment: I'd expect that the problem appears earlier. `state.workstation.recordId` - there's no recordId key! It's an array. If you're sending `{recordId:undefined,agency:undefined}` in network request (it's up to you to debug it), no wonder you get 404.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you for all this. I'll mock it up in a static API and repost. Not sure how that will help since the return is based on what I send in the body to the backend. Then the back end collects that and morphs the API that gives me back the info I need. I have no idea how that is written since it's done by someone else in C# But I'll give it a try.

Comment: You likely need to debug what's send to backend and from it. You can control "to" with a breakpoint and in dev tools network Request, and "from" is available in Response. If it fits your expectations, you can mock API call. If it doesn't then that's the problem that needs to be addressed first.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `debugger;` in your code instead of `console.log` to create a breakpoint, and inspect everything in your browser's debug tools.

I can't really help because there are very confusing things:

```
state: {
  lockboxes: [],
  workstation: []
},
```

So both are arrays.

But then:

```
setWorkstation: (state, workstation) => (state.workstation = workstation),
assignAgency(workstation) { workstation.assign = !workstation.assign},
```

It seems that `workstation` is not an array?

And also this, in the getters:

```
singleWorkstation: state => {
  let result = {
    ...state.workstation,
    ...state.lockboxes
  };
  return result;
}
```

I'm not understanding this. You're creating an object by `...`ing arrays? Maybe you meant to do something like:

```
singleWorkstation: state => {
  let result = {
    ...state.workstation,
    lockboxes: [...state.lockboxes]
  };
  return result;
}
```

Unless lockboxes is not an array? But it's named like an array, it's declared as an array. You do have this however:

```
const postdata = {
    recordId: state.workstation.recordId,
    agency: state.lockboxes.recordId
};
```

So it seems it's not an array?

Finally, in your `updageAgency` method, and this is where the problem may lie:

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axiosInstance
      .post("Workstation/update", postdata)
      .then(({ data, status }) => {
        if (status === 200) {
          resolve(true);
          commit("setWorkstation", data.data);
          commit("assignAgency", workstation);

          console.log(state);
        }
      })
      .catch(({ error }) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
```

The `.then` first arg of axios is only invoked if the status code is 2xx or 3xx. So your test `if (status === 200)` is superfluous because errors would not get there. And if for a reason of another you have a valid code other than 200, the promise never ends. `reject` is never called, as it's not an error, and neither is `resolve`. So you should remove check on the status code.

You should also call `resolve(true)` after the two `commits`, not before...

Finally your mutation assignAgency is declared all wrong:

```
assignAgency(workstation) { workstation.assign = !workstation.assign},
```

A mutation always takes the state as the first param. So it should either be:

```
assignAgency(state, workstation) { 
    state.workstation = {...workstation, assign: !workstation.assign}
},
```

Or

```
assignAgency(state) { 
    state.workstation = {...state.workstation, assign: !state.workstation.assign}
},
```

Depending on if you even need the `workstation` argument, given that what you want is just toggle a boolean inside an object.

TLDR: I'm not sure if `lockboxes` should be an array or an object, remove the status check inside your axios callback, fix the `assignAgency` mutation, use breakpoints with `debugger;` and the VueJS chrome plugin to help examine your store during development.

Comment: The states are empty arrays that get populated with the pieces of state that are mutated. The getter, I'm not too sure I did it right. I was trying to combine both states in it but I was throwing a rock in the dark. Your suggestion didn't work. The mutations are built that way to mutate the close value in the API array. Your suggestion to the mutations also didn't change the value and the mutations never fire. One mutation sets the state in its new form and the another commit to a mutation changes the value of a piece of state in it. Probably it can be done better.

Comment: @LOTUSMS you should do thing one by one instead of trying to do the whole thing at once. You're saying that the states are arrays but then you are assigning them a single object. You need to review your whole code or try on a simpler example.

Comment: I could show you an example in the same file that works. And also the way that I have it working by managing the mutation from the Vue file directly, but I don't want to overcomplicate the question. If we could chat, I could send you the code you need to see and if you figure it out, I'll still reward you the bounty here. BTW, I changed the states to objects and it didn't change the outcome.

Comment: If you can help, I can make a video showing you the screen and Vue console as well as the entire store file and page file. Better than putting all that code in here.

Comment: @LOTUSMS Sorry, I'll have to decline. My advice is just the same: start by doing something small that works, then add stuff until it doesn't work, and find the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In an action, you get passed 2 objects

```
async myAction(store, payload)
```

the store object is the whole vuex store as it is right now. So where you are getting commit, you can get the state like so

```
async fetchLockboxes({ commit,state }) {//...}
```

Then you can access all state in the app.

Comment: I already have access in that action. I'm trying to get access to lockboxes in the updateAgency action. I am already using state as an object there and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You may use **rootState** to get/set whole state.

```
 updateAgency: ({ commit, rootState , state }, { workstation, lockboxes }) {
  rootState.lockboxes=[anything you can set ]
 }
```

Comment: This is a little vague. The bounty is set for complete answers. Adding the rootState still gave me an undefined for lockboxes.recordId which is the piece of state I can't reach